# PHP 404 Error Message

Tags: php

I have begun learning PHP using an eBook. The following strange results are happening: Per the book I have created two simple PHP files. They are named phpinfo.php and hello.php. Both files show in the user root directory. Both files show when I use the ls command in my mac terminal.

When I try to run them in my browser only the first one runs. The second results in a 404 error, File Not Found. How is this possible?  Could an internal file mistake cause this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're wanting help, I suggest you post the code of the file that's causing you problems. Also, check the permissions of the file, and any error logs. Potentially the virtualhost you're using to host the page too.

Comment: Are you using Mamp as local server?

Comment: how do you 'run' the php files? what server are you running in your mac to serve the php pages?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.  It was suggested that it would be easier to delete everything including the app and start over.  So I did and then downloaded MAMP.  That worked.